# How to select and paste on the last empty row on google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a range to another place within the sheet, but I need to insert this values on the last empty row. Similar to inserting a record.

**Google apps script:**

```
 function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D13:H19').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('FieldTest'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate(); //I need to select here, the last empty row
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!D13:H19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('FieldTest');
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ssh.getRange('D13:H19').copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```